# Difference between adding spatial layer from MSSQL through "browser" and "add MSSQL table"

Tags: qgis, spatial-database, sql-server-spatial, geography-data-type, geometry-data-type

So I am trying to pinpoint the difference of adding layers from MSSQL Database that contains spatial layers like geography and geometry.

I have noticed that when adding from the browser it retains it in one layer meaning that the spatial layers are all in one file so both geometry and geography are in one layer while adding a spatial layer from add MSSQL layer on the side panel breaks my layer into four namely polygon,multipolygon,points,and another polygon and each layer has a specific spatial layer.

I was just wondering if anyone notice that and why it does that. Further what is the best way to upload your spatial layer data from Databases.